# connecting to virtualBox via RDP and GUI is not correct

Tags: java, ubuntu, xrdp

I've a installed a virtualbox under windows 10 and installed a Ubuntu 18.04 as Virtual Server and everything is running fine.
now i'm connecting to this server via windows computer using rdp which is also running fine.
but...
when i run an application written in java (developed in netbeans 8.2 under windows 10 )which is using GUI as user interface I get the following problem:
1. The Font is not the right one.
2. Some components background colors are not displayed.
3. Some components are even mixed with each others JTextField and jLable.

any exmplantion why is this happening?

Comment: I don't think it's a problem related to rdp! I haven't used swing for a long time but from what I remember it was possible to set the loook and feel, most likely the 2 systems you described above use different looks and feel. Take a look here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html , maybe it can help.

Comment: thanks for the hint, I'll check the look and feel and see which is compitable between windows and linux

Comment: Glad to help... it was a little help, I don't manage with swing for a very long time but maybe it could help you!